# Beginners query in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

```
//index.html

<html>
    <head>
        <title>An Ember dice roller</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Guest/Downloads/ember/starter-kit-1.0.0/js/app.js"></script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" >
      <h1>Dice Roller</h1>

      {{#link-to 'roll'}}Click here{{/link-to}}
      {{#link-to 'index'}}Go to index{{/link-to}}

      {{outlet}}
    </script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="roll">
           Hi!
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <p>
        Our content goes here
    </p>
    </script>



    </body>
</html>

//app.js

var Roller = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_BINDINGS: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION: true,
    LOG_VERSION: true,
    debugMode: true
});

Roller.Router.map(function () { 
    this.resource('index');
    this.resource('roll');
});
```

What is wrong with this code?
I am getting the following error. My index.html page doesn't load anything.
I am beginner for ember.js.Can anyone please help me?
Assertion failed: The URL '/' did match any routes in your application

Answer (score 0):

By default ember create something like this:

```
Roller.Router.map(function () { 
    this.route('index', { path: '/' });
});
```

But your router is overriding the index route with this:

```
this.resource('index');
```

So to be able to render the index template you will need to access your app with `http://yourhost/#/index` intead of `http://yourhost/`.

If you update your router mapping, and remove `the this.resource('index')` all will works:

```
Roller.Router.map(function () { 
    this.resource('roll');
});
```

This is a updated jsbin with this working http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1499/edit